# Are Kapoti and Unchha methods one and same?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, grihastha

While enumerating the lifestyles allowed to Grihastha, Vyasa told the following statement

> That kingdom grows in prosperity where these highly deserving persons
> live, viz., those that lead a life of domesticity according to the
> Kumbhadhanya method, **they that lead it according to the Unchha method,
> and they that lead it according to the Kapoti method.**
>
> [[Section 243, Mokshadharma Parva, Santi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b070.htm)

My doubt is about the similarity or difference between the Unchaa method and Kapoti method.

Foot note is saying that Kapoti and Unchha are one and the same

> The fourth kind of conduct, called **kapoti is also called unchha**. It
> consists of collecting such seeds of grain as have fallen down from
> the ears and as have been abandoned by the reapers.

But, I can't come into agreement with the footnote due to the two following reasons

1. When I search in dictionary about [Unchha vritti](https://andhrabharati.com/dictionary/index.php?w=%E0%B0%AE%E0%B0%BE%E0%B0%A6%E0%B0%BF%E0%B0%97), the same procedure mentioned in the footnote is present. And although Kapota vriti is not present in the dictionary explicitly, I guess that people living with Kapota vriti live only on air.
2. If both are same, then why do Vyasa mention it twice as well as separate.

With this context, are both same? If no, what actually is Kapoti method?

Comment: See second last footnote 191:3 - it says Aswasthana is Unchha.

Comment: Oh! both are different then.... @Archit But, I don't know what grihastra need to do if she want to follow kapoti method.

Comment: Okay. I don’t know any of these words but as per [Hindi dictionary](https://www.pustak.org/index.php/dictionary/word_meaning/कपोत-वृत्ति), Kapota vritti means spend immediately when you get. Don’t save anything for future.

Comment: **kapota** = pigeon/bird - which only takes food for one day, it doesn't know to save for future. **unccha** = picking up fallen food grains, which you can do to save for more than a day. so kapota implies unccha, but not other way around. there is one even higher called **Ajagara** (Python), where person sits in one place, never moves, and only eats what falls in his lap/hand. @Archit

Comment: @mar Okay thanks didn’t know this